# Как работать с Realm + RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Я вот никак не могу понять как правильно их подружить. Может гдето есть пример или туториал? Все вопиют что это круто но инфы в интернете - 0. Есть малюсенький пример на офф сайте [Realm](https://realm.io/news/using-realm-with-rxjava/) но это слишком солжно и мало.

Comment: Глянул пример - вроде все понятно и прозрачно. Подозреваю, что у вас просто мало опыта в Rx. Рекомендую для начала поиграть в песочнице с RxJava, пообсервить туда-сюда - после этого вопросы должны в большей части отпасть.

Comment: Если для вас сложный туториал от Realm, мб не стоит тогда начинать? 
По мне это из самых показательных ресурсов по составлению доков. 
rxJava и rxAndroid это разные вещи хотя имеют одинаковый принцип Reactive. rxAndroid довольно новая вещь и не имеет ещё сформированного - правильного подхода (структуры) для использования. 
Поэтому нужно изучить, и использовать свои умения для реализации, выполнения текущей задачи.